# Markov chain whose state space is the unit circle

Tags: probability-theory

I have another problem from Koralov-Sinai that I don't know how to do and I would appreciate help please. It goes like this:

5.16. Consider a Markov chain whose state space is the unit circle. Let the density of the transition function $P(x,dy)$ be given by $p(x,y) = \frac{1}{2 \epsilon}$ if the angle $(y,x) < \epsilon$ and $0$ otherwise. Find the stationary distribution.

Thank you all!

Comment: The definite article is a giveaway -- if there's only one stationary distribution and the transition function exhibits rotational symmetry, what would you expect regarding the symmetry properties of the stationary distribution?

Comment: can you post a complete answer please? I'm struggling with the concepts...

Comment: I'm assuming you mean we get a reversible distribution... but I don't see how to prove it

Comment: I'm still lost with this; can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The rotationally invariant density $p(\phi)=(2\pi)^{-1}$ for the angle $\phi$ is stationary because the transition density exhibits rotational symmetry,

Comment: I'm following Koralov and Sinai and there they don't talk about general Markov chains very clearly, so that's why I'm finding difficuties following. Again, would you be kind and write me a more detailed answer so that I could understand what you're saying? It seems like everything should be pretty easy - so I just want to understand the theory

Comment: @Dquik: Sorry, I thought I'd spelled it out by writing out the density -- could you be more specific about what aspect of this you don't understand?

Comment: why $2/\pi$ and not $1 / 2\pi$?

Comment: @Dquik: Sorry about that; you're right of course. Fixed. I hope that implies you've gained some understanding of the answer? :-)